# Trying to build shopizer in eclipse using maven

Tags: java, spring, maven, jar, shopizer

[image]When i am trying to build shopizer I m getting this error(Shown in image).
It say that the 2.0.1-snapshot.jar is missing in the maven repositories.But I have the jar at the given location of the project but it has .lastupdated extension (2.0.1-snapshot.jar.lastupdated) and I am getting this error every time.Please help me with that.

Comment: Can any one solve this issue...

Comment: why you are trying to build 2.0.1 ? why you are not trying with 2.0.2?

Comment: @UmeshAwasthi 2.0.2 is not working and I found that there are many bugs in 2.0.2 which is not let the project to be build.  I found this suggestion on stackoverflow.

Comment: If u already build this project in eclipse then please let me know.I need help to build it.Thank you :)

Comment: We have release 2.0.3, please take time to test new release and let us know in case you are still facing build issue.